# KivyMD: How do I automatically display an MDList generated in the python file

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Thanks for taking a look. I'm brand new to Kivy/KivyMD/programming and there's something fundamental I'm just not grasping between the python code and the kv code.

I'm building a simple app that uses ScreenManager to switch between two screens.
On each screen, I plan to have a dynamically generated list with data from a database.

I can add static lists and other widgets by putting them in the kv file. But I can't seem to understand how to create/update data in the class in the python file and have it link to the kv file ID.

In the following code, the program works and I've thrown a button in there that successfully generates a list, but the goal is to have no button and have the list generate automatically when the app starts.

I've added some comments with things I've tried. Am I using the wrong variable names or doing something fundamentally wrong?

[main.py python file]

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem


class FirstWindow(Screen):
    print('This prints automatically when App launches')

    # But adding widgets doesn't happen automatically
    # I tried variations but the variable is always not defined
    #self.ids.list_one.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text='List Item 1'))
    #root.ids.list_one.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text='List Item 1'))
    #ids.list_one.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text='List Item 1'))

    # This function works when called from a button
    def button_push(self):
        for i in range (20):
            self.ids.list_one.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=f'List Item {i}'))

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MultiscreenApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('Multiscreen.kv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MultiscreenApp().run()
```

[Multiscreen.kv file]

```
WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:
        name: 'firstwindow'
    SecondWindow:
        name: 'secondwindow'


<FirstWindow>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            title: 'SCREEN 1'

        Button:
            text: 'List maker button'
            on_release: root.button_push()

        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: list_one

        MDFloatingActionButton:
            elevation: 8
            icon: 'plus'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
            on_press:
                app.root.current = 'secondwindow'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'

<SecondWindow>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            title: 'SCREEN 2'

        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: list_two

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: 'Go Back'
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'firstwindow'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `__init___` method with `Clock.schedule_once` to trigger the list creation. Modified code is below. I haven't changed the rest of the code, just added two functions to show automatic list creation.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivy.clock import Clock

class FirstWindow(Screen):
    print('This prints automatically when App launches')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_list)
        
    def create_list(self, *args):
        for i in range (20):
            self.ids.list_one.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=f'List Item {i}'))
    # But adding widgets doesn't happen automatically
    # I tried variations but the variable is always not defined
    #self.ids.list_one.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text='List Item 1'))
    #root.ids.list_one.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text='List Item 1'))
    #ids.list_one.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text='List Item 1'))

    # This function works when called from a button
    def button_push(self):
        for i in range (20):
            self.ids.list_one.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=f'List Item {i}'))

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MultiscreenApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('Multiscreen.kv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MultiscreenApp().run()
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much. I'm still fuzzy about the super function. I understand inheritance but the pieces aren't fully clicking yet in my brain. I'll keep studying.

Comment: The overloaded ```super``` function is needed in the ```__init__``` method to avoid segmentation fault.

Comment: how to add each list_item id?

Answer (score 1):

```
class FirstWindow(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        """Event fired when the screen is displayed: the entering animation is
        complete."""

        def on_enter(interval):
            for i in range (20):
                self.ids.list_one.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=f'List Item {i}'))

        Clock.schedule_once(on_enter)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works too. You've given me options and helped me understand the bigger picture a little better.